# Request for 32bit travis build machine

Tags: travis-ci

It seems that travis provisions a 64bit build machine by default when a integration process starts.

Is there any options that I can use in .travis.yml to request a 32bit Ubuntu build machine?

I really need 32bit OS, because the 64Bit Ubuntu refuse to install 32bit supporting libraries (ia32-libs).

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: This is not a Travis problem at all. Ask for help with your Ubuntu issues in the appropriate forum.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such option (at least for now). See this issue: [#986 travis_ci: Add 32-bit environments](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/986)

> **@roidrage commented on 23 Jul 2015:**
>
> Closing this issue for now, as we have no immediate plans to add this feature.
>
> Should we add it to the roadmap eventually, we'll make sure to update this ticket.

Answer (score 2):

Travis supports a [number of architectures](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-cpu-architectures/) using the `arch:` key. Unfortunately, none of these are 32-bit.

'shoogle' at https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5770 suggests that it is possible to run a 32-bit image within a 64-bit container, by adding the following to `.travis.yml`:

```
services:
- docker
script:
- "docker run -i -v \"${PWD}:/MyProgram\" toopher/centos-i386:centos6 /bin/bash -c \"linux32 --32bit i386 /MyProgram/build.sh\""
```

And [dlang](https://wiki.dlang.org/Continuous_Integration) suggest:

```
env:
 - ARCH="x86_64"
matrix:
  include:
    - {os: linux, d: dmd-2.071.0, env: ARCH="x86", addons: {apt: {packages: [[gcc-multilib]]}}}
    - {os: linux, d: ldc-1.0.0, env: ARCH="x86", addons: {apt: {packages: [[gcc-multilib]]}}}
script:
 - dub test --arch "$ARCH"
```